# Python Koans singleton tuple

Tags: python

I'm stuck passing one of the singleton tuple tests, "test_tuples_of_one_look_peculiar" from Greg Malcolm's Python Koans (https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans/blob/master/python3/koans/about_tuples.py).

Specifically, the only answer I have come up with (or found on search) for

`self.assertEqual(__, ("I'm a tuple",))`

is tautological self-reference:

`self.assertEqual(("I'm a tuple",), ("I'm a tuple",))` 
which leaves the learning or purpose of the test begging. Yes, x==x.

Is the answer as simple as Python Zen's, TOOWTDI, or is there another equivalence to the singleton tuple constructor, `(value,)`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like "Fill in the blank for `self.assertEqual(__, tuple(["I'm a tuple"]))`" would have made for a more interesting exercise.

Comment: Ah!  Nice. Tried tuple with the string, which yields each individual character as a member, but casting a list, didn't think of it.  Thank you @chepner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an uninformative exercise because there are many ways of writing the creation of a singleton tuple. For example:

```
tuple(["I'm a tuple"])
tuple({"I'm a tuple"})
# ... etc. for other sequence types

("I'm a tuple",)

# or even
def single_value():
    yield "I'm a tuple"

tuple(value for value in single_value())

# or something ludicrous
next(map(tuple, [["I'm a tuple"]]))
```

Or even a criminally insane idea like this:

```
In [43]: class TuplePiper(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, value):
    ...:         self.value = value
    ...:
    ...:     def __rshift__(self, other):
    ...:         return other([self.value])
    ...:     

In [44]: TuplePiper("I'm a tuple") >> tuple
Out[44]: ("I'm a tuple",)
```

Unless the exercise comes with an identifying assumption or constraint that explains which from among these possibilities is supposed to satisfy the test, then it would seem to be just a matter of preference.